# jQuery: Clone input fields on click work, but select box values cannot be changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to add a new row which consists of an input field and a select box when you click the "ADD PHONE" button. The problem i'm facing, is that when I clone the elements, they seem to clone fine, however, the select-box doesn't seem to work. I cannot change it to a different value. Also, if the values are filled out, before the "add" button is clicked, the newly added fields will have contain the same values. Another issue is that if I have 2 sets of fields, when I click the "ADD PHONE" button, it will close both, and append both.

So here are my questions:
1) How can I get the cloned select box to work
2) How can I make sure that the cloned fields are empty
3) How can I clone just 1 at a time

I would greatly appreciate the help.

HTML

```
<button id="add-phone-button">Add Phone</button>
<div class="phone-details">
    <div id="phone-number" class="col-xs-8">
        <label for="phone" class="invisible">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" class="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
    </div>
    <div id="phone-type" class="col-xs-4">
        <label for="usage" class="invisible">Usage</label>
        <select id="usage" />
            <option selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#add-phone-button').click(function() {
    $('.phone-details #phone-number, .phone-details #phone-type').clone().appendTo('.phone-details:last-child');
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/abLun3fp/1/

Comment: Probably because you have a lot of duplicating ID's...

Comment: @tymeJV, well, actually it can work even with duplicated IDs, even though, of course, it is very bad practise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The problem occurs because jQuery Mobile wraps `<select>` with additional HTML tags and adds event listeners to them. The trick is to replace wrapped HTML with original `<select>` and to trigger initialization on it after appending to page:

   ```
   clone.find('.ui-select').html(function() { return $(this).find('select')[0].outerHTML });
   clone.appendTo('.phone-details');
   clone.find('select').parent().enhanceWithin();
   ```
2. You can empty all `<input>`s values in clone before adding its to page:

   ```
   clone.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
   ```
3. It can be achieved using `:first`:

   ```
    $('.phone-info:first')
   ```

or with your original HTML:

```
     $('.phone-details #phone-number:first, .phone-details #phone-type:first')
```

Since using multiple elements with same ID is strongly discouraged, I changed them to classes.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abLun3fp/16/)

HTML:

```
<button id="add-phone-button">Add Phone</button>
<div class="phone-details">
    <div class="phone-info">
        <div class="phone-number col-xs-8">
            <label for="phone" class="invisible">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-type col-xs-4">
            <label for="usage" class="invisible">Usage</label>
            <select name="usage">
                <option selected="selected">Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#add-phone-button').click(function()
{
    var clone = $('.phone-info:first').clone();
    clone.find('.ui-select').html(function() { return $(this).find('select')[0].outerHTML });
    clone.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    clone.appendTo('.phone-details');
    clone.find('select').parent().enhanceWithin();
});
```

If you somewhy want to stay with your original HTML, here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abLun3fp/17/) with fixed JS and original HTML.

**Update**. Thanks to @Omar for pointing out an error with `<input>` and for `.enhanceWithin()`.

Comment: Thanks Regent for your help. Everything works perfectly now!!

Comment: @SimonS. you're welcome. Just don't forget that jQuery Mobile wraps nearly everything and that duplicated IDs usually make things difficult.

Comment: Note that input is being wrapped twice. you need to unwrap it once cloned before re-creating it. and use `.enhanceWithin()` instead of `.trigger("create")`.

Comment: @Omar don't know how comes that I didn't notice that `<input>` is wrapped twice :)

Comment: Because you clone input and wrapping `div.ui-input`. So when you created the input again, JQM wraps it in `div.ui-input`. Apart from that, nice answer and thanks for considering my comment :)